# Getting index name for the max value in DF

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, max

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'Algorithm': ['KNN', 'Decision Tree', 'SVM', 'Logistic Regression'], 
        'Jaccard': [0.75,0.65,0.67,0.70], 
        'F1-score': [0.69,0.78, 0.75, 0.77], 
        'LogLoss': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 5.23]}
report= pd.DataFrame(data = data)
report = report[['Algorithm', 'Jaccard', 'F1-score', 'LogLoss']]
report.set_index(report['Algorithm'], inplace = True)
report.drop(columns = ['Algorithm'], inplace = True)
```

What i want to do is to print out the name of the index with the highest value in the dafaframe. It would be something like this:

```
print(report['Jaccard'][index_name_with_highest_value])
```

it should yield:

```
'KNN'
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Use `print (report['Jaccard'].idxmax())`

Comment: JUST EDITED A MISSING BRACKET ']' AT THE END OF THE LINE 'F1-SCORE'

Comment: @jezrael thank you!! it works!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `np.where`:

```
print(report.index[np.where(report['Jaccard'].max())[0][0]])
```

Updated Try `np.where`:

```
print(report['Algorithm'][np.where(report['Jaccard'].max())[0][0]])
```

Or `idxmax`:

```
print(report['Jaccard'].idxmax())
```

Update:

```
print(report['Algorithm'][np.where(report['Jaccard']==report['Jaccard'].max())[0][0]])
```

@jezrael's solution is also very good:

```
print(report.index[report['Jaccard'] == report['Jaccard'].max()])
```

Comment: hi, that doesn't work since 'Algorithm' is no longer a column, it's the column index name instead.

Comment: @Miguel2488 Edited mine

Comment: Thank you!! the first solution of the three you provided don't work. But the other 2 are correct!! :)

Comment: @Miguel2488 Yeah the first wasn't updated, please accept if it works, happy that i helped,

Comment: i gotta wait 2 more minutes before i can accept it. the system won't let me. But rest asured, your answered will be marked as correct. Thanks again :D

Comment: @Miguel2488 , happy that it works, happy that i helped!!!

Comment: Just have one more question. What if i have 2 max identical values and i want to display the 2 of them? Using this code it will only print the first one it encounters but not the second. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Miguel2488 Sorry for late edit, it's done!

Comment: If multiple `max` values better is use `report.index[report['Jaccard'] == report['Jaccard'].max()]`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks i'll edit

Comment: @jezrael done!!

Comment: Hi guys, thanks to both of you it really helped!! These kind of things are tricky to do

Comment: @Miguel2488 happy to help put, hope well!